# get_posts ignoring 'category' and displaying all posts

Tags: categories, get-posts, admin-menu, nginx

I'm going a bit crazy on this one. I'm trying to display a list of posts in a category on an Admin page in a plugin I am writing. The following code works fine on my dev server (OS X/Apache):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $pageSize,
    'offset'=> $offset,
    'category' => 9
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $key => $aPost) {
    (...)
}
```

As you might suspect, I get only posts in the category with an ID of 9. Now, on my production server (Linux/Nginx) it shows all posts - as if the category argument was never set. I only mention the nginx/apache/linux/os x as everything else is running the same - same themes and plugins installed (with the exception of Jetpack on the production server).

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried deactivating the Jetpack plugin?

Comment: You said you have the same themes and plugins, but what about PHP version/ activated PHP modules (long shot there)? Did you import the dev database so that all ID's are the same in production?

Comment: PHP on production is 5.4.6 while on the dev server is  5.3.26 - do you really thing the php version could do it? Given that they are both fairly up to date? As far as the ID#s, it isn't responding to *any* id version. So on production, it just ignores 'category' as if it wasn't there, regardless of the value.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yep - tried jetpack deactivation didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. After a frustrating weekend I have a workaround (but still not real reason why the simpler version worked on one install and not another!)

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $pageSize,
    'offset'=> $offset,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', 
            'field' => 'term_id', 
            'terms' => 9
        )
);
```

While this is a totally workable solution, I'm still baffled.